# Question migrated to superuser and then deleted

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, asking-questions, migrated

Why was the question https://serverfault.com/questions/354781/how-to-access-setup-of-this-router?noredirect=1 migrated to super user? I mean, doesn’t network equipment belong here?

EDIT: The question was closed as offtopic at superuser, and then somehow deleted. PLEASE do not remove this valuable piece of knowledge!

EDIT 2: Also [asked](https://meta.superuser.com/q/4174/101850) on meta.superuser.

EDIT 3: I have no objection to this being closed, as long as it will not be deleted.

Comment: [SF FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq): *"If your question is about … networks [...] and it is **not about** ... Networking outside the professional workplace"*. It even says [SOHO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_office/home_office) on the device, and you don't know the model. How much more outside the professional workplace can you get?

Comment: @DanielBeck I don’t have problem with it being migrated. I have problem with it being migrated, closed, flagged for migration back and **then deleted**.

Comment: @DanielBeck BTW, we have a [tag:soho] tag.

Comment: … with 9 questions, three of them closed or migrated. Having a tag doesn't make it perfectly on-topic either.

Comment: Undelete it or I’m going to email the staff.

Comment: Emailing the staff does nothing but get you ignored unless the problem is one that the moderation staff can't handle. As it happens, [SuperUser rejected the migration](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4174/question-migrated-from-serverfault-here-and-then-deleted/4175#4175), so I've reopened it.

Comment: ...and I've voted to close it as OT. Let's shut this one down and get back to business.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it was migrated because of this

[image]

SOHO equipment is generally considered the realm of SuperUser.